# USB Cards- Any speed advantage using a PCI Express slot over a PCI slot?

Tags: usb

I have an older custom PC. I had a PCI card for USB expansion slots but the card died after a mouse got in. It's getting hard to locate new replacement PCI boards for this but I can get a USB 3.0 card using PCI Express x1 or x16. The PCI slot runs at 33MHz and the Express slots run at 100 MHZ. Is there any advantage in using the Express slots?

Comment: I would say *speed* as the main advantage, based on the specific bandwidths of the PCI and PCI-E. Probably the PCI interface would bottleneck the USB, while PCI-E has bandwidth in the order of Gb/s. The specifics can be looked on Wikipedia, though.

Comment: Besides this, If you're upgrading from an USB 1 or 2 to an USB 3.0 card, then there will be an increase in speed, because of advancements in the USB protocol, if the connecting devices support USB 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

As you say yourself, PCI Express has a much higher bandwidth, especially if you use multiple lanes. If you only need to attach USB 2.0 devices then you don't need the additional bandwidth, so PCI would be enough. If you can take advantage of USB 3.0 (perhaps in future), go for PCI Express/USB 3.0. If you want to attach USB 3.0 disks, multiple lanes might have a small advantage. USB 3.0 shouldn't be a problem with USB 2.0 devices, so that isn't a reason aginst USB 3.0.